# How do I use useSelector in this code for selectOrigin

Tags: react-native, google-maps

I want to change pass selectOrigin.location.lat in the initialRegioin
but am unable to do so. I was watching a tutorial where they use useSelect and pass

```
const origin=useSelector(selectOrigin)
```

but this worked when Map was a function, not a class. Kindly help me with this.I referred the documentation and couldn't understand also the previous error is fixed.
Kindly help me with this :)
Thanks in advance!!!

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";



import MapView,{Marker,Polygon} from 'react-native-maps';
import { useSelector,connect } from 'react-redux';

import { selectOrigin } from '../slices/navSlice';

class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reports: [],
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      error: null,

     
    }
  
}
  
  
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jo780-full/c42f65154fac8d3d6e495326211e15b7/raw/20e8af7285f9ae5c1328e00cc79b1e2711bd446a/student.json',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ reports: data.report })
      })
      .catch(console.error)
  }
  mapMarkers = () => {

    return this.state.reports.map((report) => <Marker
      key={report.id}
      coordinate={{ latitude: report.latitude, longitude: report.longitude }}
      title=" student parking spot"
      description="available"
    >
    </Marker >)
    
  }
   mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      origin: selectOrigin

    }
}
  render() {
  
  return (
    
    <MapView

    
    mapType="mutedStandard"
    showsUserLocation={true}
        followUserLocation={true}
        zoomEnabled={true}
    style={tw`h-full w-full`}
    initialRegion={
      {
        latitude: this.mapStateToProps.origin.location.lat,
        longitude:this.mapStateToProps.origin.location.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }
    }
  >
    
    
    

    {this.mapMarkers()}
  



      
  
  

 
    {/*student area*/}
    <Polygon
    coordinates={[
      { latitude: 12.908764862118488,   longitude: 77.56763368009942 },
      { latitude: 12.909351220825277,longitude:  77.56756522139399 },
      { latitude: 12.909496879375817,longitude:  77.56763847998074 },
      {latitude:12.909506790161094,longitude: 77.56779777527214},
      {latitude:12.909333117614427, longitude:77.56856604008081},
      {latitude:12.909124598612156,longitude: 77.56852690728837},
      { latitude: 12.909385294896701,  longitude: 77.5681230870149, },
      {latitude:12.909061025711033, longitude:77.5681799298621},
      {latitude:12.909050854045336,longitude:  77.56815645018665},
      { latitude:12.90868749725228, longitude: 77.56800790948633},
      { latitude: 12.908710622492181 , longitude: 77.56762153367315 },


    ]}
    fillColor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)"
    strokeColor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)" // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
    strokeColors={[
      '#7F0000',
      '#00000000', // no color, creates a "long" gradient between the previous and next coordinate
      '#B24112',
      '#E5845C',
      '#238C23',
      '#7F0000'
    ]}
    strokeWidth={1}
  />
   <Polygon
    coordinates={[
      { latitude: 12.909394643253528,longitude:   77.56614422503371 },
      { latitude: 12.909456079146613, longitude:  77.56582255987011 },
{ latitude:12.90941582804595,longitude: 77.56577909160477},
{latitude:12.90938405085663, longitude:77.56579213208437},
{ latitude:12.909368162260469, longitude:77.56582255987011},
{latitude:12.90934168126461,longitude: 77.56586602813547},
{ latitude:12.908920103432747, longitude:77.56579430549765},
{latitude:12.908892563147631, longitude:77.56606489544944}
    ]}
    fillColor="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1)"
    strokeColor="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)" // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
    strokeColors={[
      '#7F0000',
      '#00000000', // no color, creates a "long" gradient between the previous and next coordinate
      '#B24112',
      '#E5845C',
      '#238C23',
      '#7F0000'
    ]}
    strokeWidth={1}
  />
  {/*Hospital  */}
     <Polygon
    coordinates={[
      { latitude:12.908518776874924,longitude:  77.56518322273905 },
      { latitude: 12.908724009086619,  longitude: 77.56522814973901 },
      { latitude:12.908739042012709,  longitude: 77.56516914114205 },
      { latitude: 12.908535770631334  ,longitude:   77.56512287303762},
    ]}
    fillColor="rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)"
    strokeColor="rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)" // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
  
    strokeColors={[
      '#7F0000',
      '#00000000', // no color, creates a "long" gradient between the previous and next coordinate
      '#B24112',
      '#E5845C',
      '#238C23',
      '#7F0000'
    ]}
    strokeWidth={2}
  />
  {/*Vip Parking */}
   <Polygon
    coordinates={[
      { latitude:12.909451264916404, longitude:  77.5669158882026 },

      { latitude: 12.909262624852568,  longitude:  77.56687637127314 },

      { latitude: 12.90931398237095 ,longitude: 77.56748432403379},

      { latitude:12.909400895070368, longitude:  77.56744784686815 },
      {latitude:12.909426457234511, longitude:77.56698467532628},

    ]}
    fillColor="rgba(255, 255, 50, 0.3)"
    strokeColor="rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.6)"// fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
    strokeColors={[
      '#7F0000',
      '#00000000', // no color, creates a "long" gradient between the previous and next coordinate
      '#B24112',
      '#E5845C',
      '#238C23',
      '#7F0000'
    ]}
    strokeWidth={2}
  />
 
  </MapView>

 
  
    
  )
  }
}

export default  connect(mapStateToProps) (Map)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

})
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to wrap your class component in a functional component and pass down the value as a prop. Example:

```js
const MapWrapper = () => {
  const origin = useSelector(selectOrigin);
  return <Map origin={origin} />;
});
```

And then use the `origin` prop inside your class component.

Comment: can u elaborate on how i would pass the latitude and longitude of the origin using this

Comment: the selectOrigin returns the latitude and longitude 
using the function component I did
```
initialRegion={{
latitude:origin.location.lat,
longitude:origin.location.lng,
}}
```
how do I do the same now?

Comment: The same way should work. The value of the origin won't change.